# Rails No log-in voting?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i want to create a no authentication/log in required voting system. basically anyone can vote and implement cookies and ip to limit voting. I am not using devise just act as voteable. so far the votes are not being added. i'm not sure if users are being created.

post_controller.rb

```
def current_user
  @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id])
end
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :posts do
    member do
      put "like", to: "posts#upvote"
    end
  end

 root "posts#index"

end
```

post.rb model

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_votable
end
```

Comment: show us what you've done so far. Some code or problem we can help you with

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: sorry! i'm new to this but i've added some of the code from my app.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like `acts_as_votable` *has* to associate an **identifier** with a "vote":

[image]

The identifier can be anything (it seems), which means that it can also be an `IP`:

```
#app/models/ip.rb
class Ip < ActiveRecord::Base
   # columns id | ip | user_agent | created_at | updated_at
end
```

If you make an `Ip` model (as above), you'll be able to populate it by using [`find_or_create_by`](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Relation/find_or_create_by):

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :posts do
   match :vote, via: [:post,:delete], on: :member
end

#app/controllers/posts_controller.rb
class PostsController < ApplicationController
   def vote
      @ip = Ip.find_or_create_by ip: request.remote_ip
      if request.delete?
         # remove vote
      elsif request.post?
         # add vote
      end
   end
end
```

This will allow you to store `IP` addresses (from the [`request`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html) object), which will allow you to define who has voted etc.